# How to enable a json filetype plugin in Vim

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am opening a JSON file with comments like this in vim:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */
```

etc.

It highlights those lines as if there were errors. I want it to accept those comments.

I've tried adding [vim-json](https://github.com/elzr/vim-json) plugin, both the syntax under `~/.vim/syntax/json.vim` and ftplugin under `~/.vim/ftplugin/json.vim`

But I can't get any improvements (I've read the `:help plugin` page, no luck)

**Question**

There are two ways I'd need some help:

1. How to detect if the ftplugin vim-json has been load
2. how to enable it or use another plugin.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! To be fair, comments _are_ invalid syntax for JSON, the JSON specification doesn't really allow them.

Answer (score 1):

The [neoclide/jsonc.vim](https://github.com/neoclide/jsonc.vim) plugin may be what you're looking for. It provides support for [vscode's JSON with comments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-with-comments) (jsonc) highlighting mode.

However, the plugin isn't configured to handle regular JSON files by default. You'd need to add `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.json set filetype=jsonc` to your init.vim if you intended to use the jsonc highlighting with regular JSON files